# Android - What customized file format can be used for transferring multimedia?

Tags: android, android-layout, file-upload

My Requirement is to create an android app with Small audio files, text, small animation effect which can be played. how to define a new downloadable file format which can be downloaded from the website/ transferred to other phone via Bluetooth.

Using the app, we must be able to import the file format and must be able to play the multimedia.   can you guys help me out how to proceed ?

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What about just using a zip file? (Since audio and image files are already compressed, you can simply use the "store" option for these files.)